# Google Analytics, where is event tracking in the "new version"

Tags: google-analytics

Well the question says it all, In the old version it was under `Content > Event Tracking` but in the "new version" I searched all over and can't find it anywhere.

Is it still in Google Analytics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still there, but renamed to `Events` (still under `Content`).

Comment: Is there a `Standard Reporting` tab on the big orange toolbar?

Comment: yeah, anyway I figured out what it was, for some reason I wasn't seeing the sidebar